# Дейтаграммы, сегменты, пакеты, сообщения, кадры (Какая между ними разница?)

Tags: сеть

Читаю книгу по компьютерным сетям, дошёл до объяснения каждого из уровней организации протоколов, запутался с  порциями данных, чем всё таки обмениваются конечные системы?Пакетами, сегментами, сообщениями, или кадрами?Или разницы нету?
Объясните подробно, пожалуйста.

Comment: это от уровня зависит. на каждом уровне свои понятия, которые так же зависят от конкретного протокола

Answer (score 0):

Смотря на каком уровне...

- На физическом - битами(0, 1) - это то что идёт по проводу.
- На уровне сетевой карты - битами или кадрами(Ethernet протокол).
- На уровне операционной системы - пакетами(IPv4, v6).
- А уже в приложение оно поступает в виде пакетов\датаграмм(TCP/UDP и т.д.).

То есть передача данных идёт таким путём:

1. Приложение отправляет данные программе, которая отвечает за обмен данными(драйвер сети) в виде пакета(содержит адрес получателя, порт и другую информацию).
2. Сетевой драйвер получает пакет, переводит его в формат IPv4(6), добавляя информацию об протоколе, версии, размере и прочем. После этого передаёт железной сетевой карте
3. Сетевая карта получает из пакета адрес назначения, и высылает по проводу биты данных.
4. Происходит передача данных по маршрутизаторам, доставка до получателя
5. Всё в обратном порядке